# Toast in webpage using Javascript - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null at showSnackbarMessage

Tags: javascript

Was trying to add a toast message that would pop up when i call a function, however, i am getting the below errors:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
    at showSnackbarMessage**

When i run it on y local browser, i get an error on my console that classList is empty, however, the code seems to be working here

```js
function showSnackbarMessage(message, time) {

let snackbar_Div = document.getElementById('snackbar');
snackbar_Div.classList.add("show");

  snackbar_Div.innerHTML = message;
  time=time*1000;//time is in seconds
  // After 2 seconds, remove the show class from DIV
  setTimeout(function(){ snackbar_Div.classList.remove("show")}, time);
};

showSnackbarMessage('Welcome to the page', 2);
```

```css
#snackbar {
visibility: hidden; /* Hidden by default. Visible on click */
min-width: 250px; 
margin-left: -125px; 
background-color: #333; 
color: #fff; 
text-align: center;
border-radius: 2px;
padding: 16px;
position: fixed; 
z-index: 1; 
left: 50%; 
bottom: 30px;
}

#snackbar.show {
visibility: visible;

-webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
to {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadein {
from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
to {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
from {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
to {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes fadeout {
from {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
to {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
}

/*----------       End of snackbar       ----------------*/
```

```html
      <div id="snackbar">Some text some message..</div>
```

Comment: What browser do you use ? I cannot reproduce your error and your code looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div has not loaded on the DOM and your method is called before that. classList is not empty, Javascript is just not able to find the element because it doesn't exist on the DOM.

Try calling showSnackbarMessage on `window.onload`

Comment: Makes sense: added window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    showSnackbarMessage('Welcome to the page', 2);
}) , the issue seems to have been resolved. Thank you Saksham!